# How to make only one key observable using ko.mapping

Tags: knockout.js, mapping

I am trying to make only one key observable using the knockout mapping plugin.  The data is an array of objects:

```
var data = {
    people: [
        {id: 1, age: 25}, 
        {id: 2, age: 35}
    ]
};
```

Only `age` should be observable.  I've tried these options:

```
var mappingOptions = {
    "observe": [ "people.age" ]
    // "observe": [ "people[].age" ]
    // "observe": [ "people[0].age" ]    // Works, but not what I need
}
```

[The docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html#observing_only_certain_properties_using_observe) show that I can observe a key of an object at a specific index, but this is not what I'm looking for as my data is dynamic, and besides I want all objects to have this key observable.  Unfortunately this exact usage is not documented in the docs (at this time, in any case).

Has anyone got this one working? The [jsfiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/pAHxJ/7/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of the limited collection handling capabilities of the `observe` option (so you would need to write `"observe": [ "people[0].age","people[1].age", etc ]` to make it work as you've already figured it out) the recommended pattern is to use a `create` function for your `people` collection.

In your custom `create` create function you can call `ko.mapping.fromJS` again with your `{ observe: ["age"] }` as the mapping option which will create the required items:

```
var data = {
    people: [
        {id: 1, age: 25}, 
        {id: 2, age: 35}
    ]
};
var mappingOptions = {
    people: {
        create: function(options) {
            return ko.mapping.fromJS(options.data, { observe: ["age"] });
        }
    }
}
var r = ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mappingOptions);
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wmqTx/).